# Create domain in windows Dns using C #

Tags: c#, dns

Good morning, I need to create a little program in webforms (C #) to facilitate the creation of DNS zones under Windows server 2008.

I found this class created by ademar: http://ademar.name/blog/2005/07/a-simple-net-interface-to-dnsc.html

Aparententemente should work perfectly. But during testing does not work.

On line: Execute ("/ ZoneAdd" + zone + "/ Primary / file" + zone + ".dns"); when trying to run generates a file not found error because the command / file trying to find arquivo.dns in the c:\windows\system32\dns, and the file does not exist.

I tried to create the file using C #, there can not because it generates other written permission error in this folder, even tried to add permission for my admin user and yet the permission error:

Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\dns\meusite.com.br.dns'.

Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: You know there is a command line for the DNS service? And half a dozen queries for the same topic here?

Comment: I did not see that my doubt as doubled.
The posted code did not help!

Comment: The posted code is the correct way to manipulate a Windows DNS. OBVIOUSLY this includes more than blind copy/pasting - for example finding the right method calls. This is generally called "Programming". We are not here o write your code for you - but we point you into the correct way.

Comment: I do not mean in any way a ready code, want help getting around the error explained, for example, to set some attribute that allows creation of the file in the specific folder, or something.

Comment: The correct way to manipulate the service is via WMI - which includes the SERVICE creating the zone file.

Comment: So not of to manipulate using C #?

Comment: Yes. In case you do not know, C# is a programming language. WMI is an interface to control most aspects on Windows (WIndows Management Interface). C# can use WMI. Come on, this is basics for anyone doing system management style programming.

Comment: My dear, I think that stackoverflow is made to answer questions of any kind. I also believe that it is not for this type of heavy response.If you do not want to help more repeitosa way, why participate?Returning to doubt, I will examine how to use WMI to try to manipulate the DNS.I was just waiting for an answer as to use WMI is necessary to reference this DLL or something. Anyway, I apologize for my layman hand, in the case of C # facing website.I know very well what is C #, use more than 5 years only for developing web. I'm just trying to create something for desktop, which never had contact

Comment: But after his thick clarification, I took the course of resolution and aparetentemente'm on the right track.
Thank you.